# Quel est le genre de "pendule d'échecs" ?

Tags: vocabulaire, genre, jeux

Un pendule fait référence au [corps oscillant de manière régulière](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pendule#Nom_commun_1).
Une pendule fait référence à [une horloge contenant un pendule](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pendule#Nom_commun_2).

Je cherche à connaître le genre d'un(e) pendule destiné(e) au jeu d'échecs.

**Les arguments en faveur du genre féminin :**

- Servant à mesurer spécifiquement le temps, l'objet peut être assimilé
  à une horloge complexifiée.
- L'article Wikipedia consacré [aux pendules d'échecs](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendule_d'%C3%A9checs) indique le
  genre féminin tout comme la plupart des résultats liés à cette
  recherche.

**Les arguments en faveur du genre masculin :**

- On retrouve une certaine oscillation dans le fait que le décompte est
  alterné entre les deux joueurs.
- L'objet ne contient pas à proprement parler un pendule, mais plutôt
  un minuteur.

J'ai toujours employé le genre masculin quand il s'agissait d'un(e) pendule d'échecs mais j'ai récemment été corrigé.

Quel est le genre de Pendule d'échecs ?

Comment: Pour moi, le simple fait que d'une manière ou d'une autre elle serve à mesurer/indiquer le temps signifie qu'on doit utiliser le féminin...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Le mécanisme d'horlogerie est *une pendule* (**féminin**):

> Petite horloge dont le mouvement était, à l'origine, entretenu et
>   réglé par un pendule.

De nos jours, il y a aussi de **grandes** pendules.

*Le pendule* (**masculin**) est un solide suspendu:

> Solide suspendu à un point fixe ou à un axe et qui oscille librement
>   sous l'action de la gravité après qu'on l'a mis en mouvement en
>   l'écartant de sa position d'équilibre.

Voir le [dictionnaire de l'académie](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/pendule).

Answer (score 3):

Pour moi, c'est féminin, comme tu le dis elle sert à mesurer le temps, comme une pendule.

Answer (score 0):

Jouant aux échecs régulièrement je confirme que l'on dit bien **une** pendule d'échec ou **un** chronomètre d'échec.